# Add shortcut to application's menu

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an application which adds a menu item to the android installed applications menu. I have been successful at creating homescreen menu but still want my shortcut to be added to the applications menu as well. Is this possible? if so, how can i accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Once installed all application get added to the device's Application Drawer by default, unless you specifically tell it not to.  Are you using a replacement homescreen (as some allow you to hide apps in the drawer)? Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you cannot add a shortcut icon to the list of application installed on your device but only to the homescreens.

Thanks guys